# How can I display Unicode through FXML's setText?

Tags: java, label, fxml

I've got the following problem:
If I set a Labels text as a Unicode character in its FXML file, it displays correctly:

```
<Label alignment="TOP_CENTER" minHeight="140.0" minWidth="500.0" text="&#9831;" ...>
```

[correctly displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M7V7Y.png)

However, if I try to set this label using label.setText the unicode sequence itself is being displayed:

```
label.setText("&#9831;");
```

[just unicode string](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G3pXm.png)

My Question now is: How can I get FXML to display unicode characters at runtime?

Answer (score 0):

Found solution:

```
private String fromUnicode(int unicode){
    return new String(Character.toChars(unicode));
}

slabel.setText(fromUnicode(0x2664));
```